# How to compare type at "DragEnter" event?

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop

I want to drag `UserControl` to `Panel` and do some specific action according to which type of `UserControl` i draged. In my case it can be 2 types of `UserControl` that i can drag to the panel. And when im draging, for example, first `UserControl`, i have to do A action. If i'm draging 2nd, B action should be done.
I implemented `MouseDown` event for `UserControl`. But i don't know how to implement `DragEnter` event for `Panel`. What should i compare there?
I tried to write something like that: `if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(MyType)))`, but `e.Data` have `System.Windows.Forms.DataObject` type, not `MyType`.

Answer (score -1):

is this maybe what you are looking for? with this you get the information of the file or files that are being dragged over.

```
 void MainForm_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop)) e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
                string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
                foreach (string file in files) Console.WriteLine(file);
            }
```

Comment: can the person who downvotes this also explain why?